# GIT fetch no actualiza el repositorio local

Tags: git, github, fetch, gitlab

Tengo un repositorio en remoto con unos añadidos que no tengo en mi repositorio local, así que quiero actualizarlo. He hecho "git fetch" y entiendo que se hace correctamente:

```
git fetch     
remote: Counting objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), 1.21 KiB | 24.00 KiB/s, done.
From...
```

El problema es que no veo los cambios en local, sigue todo igual. Luego, si intento ir a "origin/branchQueHeActualizado" me sale un mensaje de error:

```
git fatal: a branch named "feature/section5/already exists
```

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? ¡Gracias!

Comment: después del `fetch` qué comando corres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer `git fetch` no cambias ninguna de tus ramas **locales**. Fetch solo actualiza la información que tienes de las ramas remotas. Tendrías que hacer un merge o un rebase para que entonces tu rama reciba los cambios del "upstream".

Si prefieres que eso suceda en un solo paso (fetch/merge o fetch/rebase), considera utilizar `git pull` en vez de `git fetch`.

Comment: Gracias! Se ha solucionado haciendo un merge del branch origin al local.